# uwsgi mapping request to the process

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I have a big object (playing field) based on many sqlalchemy objects in my python application.

For each simple request (for example: move players) I must create this object and this is resource-intensive. I can cache a ready object in global variable.

But that works only if I use a single uwsgi thread.

```
cache = {}

def applicatio(field_id):
    global cache
    if field_id not in cache.keys():
        field = get_field(field_id)
        cache[field_id] = field
    field.move_player()
```

I can not use `uwsgi.cache` because my object is bigger than 64KB. And I am not sure that it good works for object based on connection to databases.

Also another problem exists - if two request arrive at the same time to different processes I can get collision.

Thus I want to map requests to same threads. In nginx I can use `hash $arg_field_id;`

But than I need to create many uwsgi processes with different sockets. IMHO it s a bad idea.

Can uwsgi realize this logic?
or

Maybe does someone know how can i share objects between processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uWSGI caches can be as big as you want, just tune them as documented here:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Caching.html#cache2-options

Btw, it is normal you approach does not work with multiple processes, as a process by-definition does not share address space with others. You could use threads (with proper locking in place when you create the area), but really, uwsgi caches are way easier (and are shared by processes automatically), and have some property useful for you:

(a potential race condition case)

thread1: uwsgi.cache_set('foo', big_data)

thread2: uwsgi.cache_set('foo', big_data)

thread3: uwsgi.cache_set('foo', big_data)

only the first one to acquire the automatic cache lock will create the new object, the others two options will be a no-op

Comment: Thanks! I was heedless, then read this documentation. I will try this in the evening.

Comment: Hm. I was right when i thought that uwsgi.cache can not cache my object.

Comment: why ? you can store any blob. Obviously if you want to store a complex python object you have to pickle/marshal/serialize it like with any other caching server

Comment: If i serialize this objects, i lose connection to the databases and then i load this object from cache, change some value and try session.commit() i get exception. But my problem was solution with changed mysql to mongodb and some changes in applications logic. Now object fast get from mongodb without many joins and selects.